# read a file and saves it in an array of string in C

Tags: c, string, file

I work with Eclipse luna, Cygwin and windows 8.

I want to read a file that contains this information:

```
    A 3.0
    B 4
    C 7
```

and store them in an array of String ** ** tabdata1.

The class Lire.h is:

```
struct String {
char *string;
};
void PSOConstants();
double data[3] ;
```

and the class Lire.C is:

```
void PSOConstants()   {
    struct String data1;
    struct String tabdata1[6];
    double copiedata[6];
    FILE* fichier= fopen("E:\\processing_Times_C\\info1.txt", "r");  
    int i=0;
    while (!feof(fichier)){
        fscanf(fichier, "%s\n", data1);
        tabdata1[i]=data1;
        printf("%s", data1);
        i=i+1;
    }
    fclose(fichier);
 }

int main(){
    PSOConstants();
    return 0;
}
```

this generates a cygwin_exception :: open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace. Knowing that all is well when I delete the two lines:

```
        tabdata1[i]=data1;
        i=i+1;
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: array index might overflow.You allocated  'struct String tabdata1[6];, but reading the file * while (!feof(fichier))' { .. }make sure you allocated enough space

Comment: No memory was allocated for `data1.string`, so `fscanf(fichier, "%s\n", data1);` is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: `data1.string = malloc(need size);fscanf(fichier, "%s\n", data1.string);`

Comment: Before writing code like `fscanf(fichier, "%s\n", data1);`, it would be good to know what `%s` expects. You're not fulfilling that. [See the documentation of the `scanf` function family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).